# MySQL Max No. of Connections Reached

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am having this strange issue ever since uploading my app to the server.  The database is very small and the app itself is only ever in use by 3 clients at a time.

I run this code via SSH terminal:

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

Now I run that code several times and noticed that the processes started with around 10 but now they're up to 50.

[image]

So I contacted support and they claim that it is a code issue but strangely the issue is always resolved (temporarily) when I reboot my VPS.

I have only one scheduled job which I dispatch in a loop:

```
foreach ($telNumbers as $tel) {
    $this->dispatch(new SendDepositSMSAlertJob($tel, $bank . ' - ' . $acNumber, $depositType, $depositAmount, $reportDate));
}
```

This is the the code for the job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;


class SendDepositSMSAlertJob extends Job
{
    private $to;
    private $account;
    private $type;
    private $amount;
    private $date;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($to, $account, $type, $amount, $date)
    {
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->account = $account;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->amount = $amount;
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Settings
        $url = "https://xxx.xxxx.com/xx/messages/send";
        $from = "XX";
        $message = urlencode($this->account." has been credited with a " . $this->type . " deposit of GHs " . $this->amount . " on " . $this->date);

        $client_id = "xxxxxx";
        $client_secret = "xxxxx";
        $query_string = "?From=".$from."&To=".$this->to."&Content=".$message."&ClientId=".$client_id."&ClientSecret=".$client_secret."&RegisteredDelivery=true";

        $response = @file_get_contents($url.$query_string);
    }
}
```

I have set my cron to execute the artisan:schedule command every 1 minute.  As you can see the above job does not really make any database calls so right now I'm wondering why there are soo many idle processes and why the connection limit is reached so easily.

Comment: A guess: persistent connections?

Comment: I do not know whether the framework uses persistent connections by default neither do I see any docs on how to check or turn it off if it did.

Comment: Also why do the numbers keep increasing or decreasing even when the app is not in use?

Comment: I seem to have the same problem, any resolution on this issue? Using Laravel Framework 5.5.28